# SFTP from one server to another in PHP application spitting out error

Tags: php, laravel, sftp

So I have a function on one server uploading a file to another server.

```
private function sftpAction($path){
    include(app_path().'/includes/sftp/Net/SFTP.php');
    include(app_path().'/includes/sftp/Crypt/RSA.php');

    $sftp = new Net_SFTP('blank');
    if (!$sftp->login('blank', 'blank')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }  else {
        // echo 'Login Successful';
        $location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/vconf/cqa/';
        die($location);
        $sftp->chdir('/cqa/vconf/');
        $sftp->put($path, $location.$path, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
        // echo $sftp->pwd();
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly fine on my local. However, as soon as I upload it to my server, I get this weird error.

> Net_SSH2::Net_SSH2(): Failed opening required 'Math/BigInteger.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')

I have made sure that all my files are in the right paths and that I have the necessary file permissions.

I am doing this in Laravel if it makes any difference. Can anyone help me identify what's wrong?

Comment: From a quick search, it seems that you might not have the `Math_BigInteger` package on the server? http://pear.php.net/package/Math_BigInteger/redirected

Comment: sure Ill try that right now...but then why would it work on my local?

Comment: Cause it was installed on your local server.

Comment: Well it worked thanks a bunch! Saved me a lot of hassle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick search, it seems that you might not have the [Math_BigInteger](http://pear.php.net/package/Math_BigInteger/redirected) package on the server?

*Posted as answer to resolve question even though it was a passing comment.*